# How can I use npm package (react-datepicker) with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have Rails 5 app with webpacker and react-rails gem.
I want to try https://reactdatepicker.com/ package.

I install it using `yarn add react-datepicker`

How can I use it in my code?

Comment: Rails (the back-end) is irrelevant here... The docs for the datepicker lib are really clear... If you're not familiar with React - maybe just start there with a basic tut...

Answer (score 0):

The [official site](https://reactdatepicker.com/) you linked doesn't appear to have docs but on [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) there's code for a basic example. Be sure to use the two "import" lines related to datepicker.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
 
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
 
// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';
 
const Example = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```